# Tell git to always ignore some file/folders when merging

Tags: git, merge

Suppose the project has following folders:

- `core`
- `src`

And have branches: `master` and `testbranch`

`src` in `master` and `src` in `testbranch` contains different content.

I want to tell git **not to merge** the `src` folder when merging `master` and `testbranch`.

In other words, I want to merge only the `core` folder between branches.

Also, I want git to track the `src` folder for individual branches just like usual files.

Is there any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience it's not possible using a single repository. You can use a git sub-module into your main branch. So your `src` folder will be as your git submodule. and the `project` folder will be as your main repository which will contain the core as well the src folder which is actually a git submodule. ( Or vice-versa )

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible afair.
Maybe you should split up `core` and `src` into different Git repositories to track them separately.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know what you are doing, that you are familiar with `git` concepts and that you are forced by circumstances (upper management or whatever) to do this. It is very against `git` ways.

That said...

#### Answer

> `src` in `master` and `src` in `testbranch` contains different content.

Then you should not have them in the same directory.

Make your directory structure like this:

```
core
src_master
src_testbranch
src --> src_master
```

`src` is then a symlink pointing to either `src_master` or `src_testbranch` depending on which branch you are in.

Now everything will work fine. The two `src_...` directories *will* show up in both branches, but you can just ignore that. You will still just work with `src`.

It is up to you whether you put the `src` symlink in `.gitignore` or not (depends on what you actually want to achieve with all this). Either way it does not matter much.

N.B.: you do not need to call the `src_...` directories after their branch names, rather name them by whatever is actually in there. You can also put them wherever else, like `dist/...` or `vendor/...`.